# remotetestng detected testng version 6.8.9 org testng testngexception

Tags: eclipse-plugin, testng

I am getting this exception :

```
[RemoteTestNG] detected TestNG version 6.8.9
Exception in thread "main" org.testng.TestNGException: 
Cannot load class from file: 
    at org.testng.internal.ClassHelper.fileToClass(ClassHelper.java:527)
    at org.testng.TestNG.configure(TestNG.java:1452)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.configure(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:74)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:235)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
```

while running my *testsuite file* from *eclipse neon 4.6.1*

my *pom.xml* has setting:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
    <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
    <version>6.8.8</version>
</dependency>
```

my classpath is also fine.

TestNG plugin installed on eclipse is 6.14.0

I am unable to execute my tests because this error.tried all options.Please help

Comment: You calling testng.xml as test suite or you calling any class or when calling from command prompt ?

Answer (score 1):

This question is a little old, did you ever find the problem? I was having the same issue, and for me, it had to do with some white space in the pom file where it was expecting a listener.

**Problem**

1. In eclipse with TestNg plugin installed
2. Properly annotated test
3. Right click / 'run as testng'
4. Result: **Exception in thread "main"** org.testng.TestNGException: Cannot load class from file: at org.testng.internal.ClassHelper.fileToClass(ClassHelper.java:551)

**Root Cause** (for me)

1. In pom.xml, mave-surefire-plugin, properties, I had a property named "listener" and the value had several long values, so I put a line break in so it would wrap to next line. This is wrong.
2. This line break causes the error described.

**Resolution**

1. Remove the line break; put it all on one long line.

This solved my problem.